# Hive - How to extract dats from a string with different formats

Tags: sql, date, hadoop, hive, simpledateformat

Hi iam trying to extract dates from the string using regex function.How to extract dates dynamically when the date format changes from mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yy. The below regexp works for mm/dd/yyyy format.What if my string has both the formats and i want to extract dates dynamically.

string1 = '2021 Flight 5 Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/25/2021 and 8/7/2021' below function works fine.

string1 = '2021 Flight 5 Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/25/21 and 8/7/21' how to extract if 2 dates in both the scenarios.

```
regexp_extract(string1, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1) date1,
regexp_extract(string1, '^.*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}).*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',2) date2
```

Comment: are you sure there are only 2 date formats, because if 8/7/2021(mm/dd/yyyy) can also be read in dd/mm/yyyy format and still be a valid date.

Comment: based on 7/25/21 iam assuming it would be mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: For starters, don't use such localized formats. Use the ISO8601 format. Right now you have absolutely no idea what formats are used. And even if one of the values is 21, you have no idea if it's a day of month, a year or even what year it is - 1921 or 2021? You just reintroduced the most expensive bug in the history of computing, Y2K. One I might add, that caused Lloyd's, Barclays and other major banks to go offline in January 2020 because their hacky fixes started treating `20` as 1920.

Comment: Specifically for `How to extract dates dynamically when the date format changes from mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yy` you can't because that's exactly what the Y2K bug is - you have no idea what that `yy` means. You can only guess. What if the fields contain customer birthdates and loan due dates? What would `30` mean in that context? `40`? That's what happened with Barclays - back in 2000 they decided that any number below `20` was in the 2000s while any number above was in the 1900s. So on January 1st 2020 - BOOM.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE expression to check different formats and parse accordingly. Two digits year is a bad practice, but if you already have such data, then nothing to do, this is common approach for parsing different formats - CASE expressions:

Demo:

```
with mytable as (

select '2021 Flight 5 Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/25/2021 and 8/7/2021' string1 union all
select '2021 Flight 5 Accessory Fixtures: DELIVER BETWEEN 7/25/21 and 8/7/21'
)

select case when string1 rlike '(?i)BETWEEN (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})'
            then date(from_unixtime (unix_timestamp(regexp_extract(string1, '(?i)BETWEEN (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1),'MM/dd/yyyy')
                       ))
            
            when string1 rlike '(?i)BETWEEN \\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2} '
            then date(from_unixtime (unix_timestamp(regexp_extract(string1, '(?i)BETWEEN (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2})',1),'MM/dd/yy')
                       ))
        end date1,
        case when string1 rlike '(?i)AND (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})'
            then date(from_unixtime (unix_timestamp(regexp_extract(string1, '(?i)AND (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})',1),'MM/dd/yyyy')
                       ))
            
            when string1 rlike '(?i)AND \\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}'
            then date(from_unixtime (unix_timestamp(regexp_extract(string1, '(?i)AND (\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2})',1),'MM/dd/yy')
                       ))
        end date2
from mytable
```

Result:

```
date1       date2   
2021-07-25  2021-08-07
2021-07-25  2021-08-07
```

In case of two digits year, unix_timestamp function will guess missing digits: 7/25/21 is parsed as 2021-07-25 and 7/25/98 parsed as 1998-07-25. There can be errors in such guess, mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation this should work for me. One more question if my string doesn't have BETWEEN and AND and it just has some other text and dates

Comment: @JayaprakashNeela change regexp accordingly of course, the general approach is the same: detect format in case and parse